# Placement of scale tick labels in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

When i use `scale ticks` in my plots i can't get those multiplicators to move anywhere. So basically i use plots like:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
 \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[scaled ticks=true]
    \addplot coordinates { (20000,0.0005) (40000,0.0010) (60000,0.0020)}; 
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
 \end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

So my Question is: How can i get this `x tick scale label` to move onto the right side of the right y-axis? So that it is above the x-axis? 
(The mind behind this question is, that i sometimes have large x-labels, which then are very close to the scale label)

Comment: I have taken the liberty of downscaling the image (for this the key `small` is quite valuable) :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use the key: `every x tick scale label` which lets you overwrite the default placements. Notice that the keyword `at` within this style refers to the absolute size of the axis environment and are ***not*** in *cm* or *pt*.

So:

```
every x tick scale label/.style={
    at={(1,0)},xshift=1pt,anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt
}
```

will make the `x` tick scale be at the graph south east corner, shifted 1 pt to the right and anchored at south west (making sure that it is not overlapping with the graph).

Inserting this in your code yields:

[image]

You can always play with the `yshift` etc. as well.

For reference, the default option for x-tick scale placement is:

```
every x tick scale label/.style={at={(xticklabel cs:0.9,5pt)},yshift=-2em,left,inner sep=0pt}
```

where you should notice that the `xticklabel cs` is the coordinate system in the x-axis. Thus you can use this to manually place it according to the x-tick labels. Try for instance:

```
every x tick scale label/.style={at={(xticklabel cs:1)},anchor=south west}
```

Comment: Great! Maybe one additional Question: where did you find it? Since i wasn't able to locate it in the manual.

Comment: It is in the manual, however, it is difficult to find unless you know the name of the keys... :)

Comment: @zeroth I tried to use this code to change the position of a the right axis tick scale label of a two y axes plot but it made no change. Is it possible to use it with two ordinates plots?