# Get the auto generated tick distance of a pgfplot (DIN 461)

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-styles, ticks

I would like to set up my pgfplots to comply with the German Standard "DIN 461". To make it short: We are asked to place the unit of the axis between the last and the second last tick label or replace the second last tick label in case there is not enough space.

What I have learned so far is, that I could make a reference to the last tick label by setting an alias for each tick label ([Placement of the scale tick label in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299298/placement-of-the-scale-tick-label-in-pgfplots)). What seems not to be achievable easily is to get the position of the second last tick label.

Alternativley I would like to get the actual tick distance, which would make it possible to recalculate the second last tick label position based on the position of the last one. Of course I could set the `tick distance` manually and therefore know the distance, but I would like to keep it as flexible as possible (e.g. to make it scalable with less effort, especially if I use `max space between ticks` and `min space between ticks`).

So to summarise my questions:

1. Is there a possibility to get the position of the second last tick label directly
2. Is there an alternative possibilty to get the auto generated tick distance

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can give the tick labels numbered names that can then be used to position a label halfway between the last two labels.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\pgfplotsset{
    din xlabel/.style={
        xticklabel style={
            name=label\ticknum,
            append after command=\pgfextra{\xdef\lastticknum{\ticknum}}
        },
        after end axis/.code={
            \pgfmathparse{int(\lastticknum-1)}
            \path (label\lastticknum.base) -- (label\pgfmathresult.base) node [midway, anchor=base] {#1};
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[din xlabel=\si{\celsius}]
      \addplot table {
      0 1
      2 1
      3 2
      4 3
      };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may find an enhanced solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516336/tick-generation-with-and-without-scale-label-din-461), which also works with a scale label.