# The scale of the X-axis bar is far away

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I am attempting to create a box plot with very large numbers(using tikzpicture), so I expect their to be smaller numbers on the X-axis but the scale denoted on the graph. THe problem is that scale is uncomfortably far away, how can I fix this?
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.  Also, the solution may be dependent on the packages that you are using and exactly how you are producing the box plot.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using `pgfplots` and an `axis` environment? If so, see if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71242/placement-of-scale-tick-labels-in-pgfplots helps.

Comment: Sorry! I am new to this, as you can tell. But thank you Torbjørn T., that really helped!